# arraylist printing error can some suggest a solution

Tags: arraylist

i need to print this arraylist can someone help. i changed from the normal double to the Double but it still will not work please help.

import java.util.*;

public class Heights {

```
static ArrayList <Double> Heights = new ArrayList <Double>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //use it  use the method
    addsomeheight(5.1);
    addsomeheight(6.2);
    addsomeheight(6.3);
    addsomeheight(5.4);
    addsomeheight(5.5);
    addsomeheight(5.6);
    addsomeheight(5.7);
    addsomeheight(5.8);
    addsomeheight(5.9);
    addsomeheight(6.9);

    //declare a new method
}
private static void addsomeheight(Double x)  {

    for (Double x1 : Heights){
        System.out.println(x1);
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any value to the list, so it's always empty. The method `addsomeheight()` doesn't add its argument to the list. It ignores it, and prints the list instead.

Please respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter, and methods are camelCased.

Comment: am new to this do really understand what u just said simplify please ?

Comment: I don't know how I could be simpler. Do you see any call to `Heights.add()` in your code? I don't see any. So you're not adding anything to the list. So it stays empty forever. So nothing is never printed, since there is no element in the list. The only things you're doing in the program with the list are 1. creating it, 2. iterating over its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
static ArrayList <Double> heights = new ArrayList <Double>();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{    
    //use it  use the method
        heights.add(5.1);
        heights.add(6.2);
        heights.add(6.3);
        heights.add(5.4);
        heights.add(5.5);
        heights.add(5.6);
        heights.add(5.7);
        heights.add(5.8);
        heights.add(5.9);
        heights.add(6.9);

     for (Double x1 : Heights)
     {
        System.out.println(x1);
     }
}
```